# OOP-correct way of notifying about a has-a relationship

Tags: oop

The has-a relationship is the following: a `Product` has a collection of `Event`s. Events are not simple primitives, they represent for example a price change.
In this scenario who is more natural to assume the responsibility to notify the current user about an `Event` on a `Product`?

If this is the `Product` - `Product#notify(Event)`.

If this is the `Event` - `Event#notify(Product)`. This one might be a little awkward/loopy, since the call in `Product` would look like this: `this.events[i].notify(this)`.

`User#notify(Product, Event)` is not an option since the system has no notion of users.